# How to update a form with error data after unsuccessful submit?

Tags: javascript, react-final-form

I am using [react-final-form](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form).

```
<Form
  onSubmit={
    (values) => makeAPICall(values).catch(e => ????)
  }
>
...
  <Field name='name'>
    ...
  </Filed>
...
</Form>
```

Lets say that the error that comes back is about the name not being unique.

I would like to set the error on the `Field` based on message from the `e`.

I can't figure out the way how to modify the form state from inside a `catch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `react-final-form` project has a codesandbox about submission error handling.
It's here: https://codesandbox.io/s/9y9om95lyp

Basically in your Forms render prop, you have to pass it a destructured object containing `submitError` and check for the presence of a submit error in your field.

```
<Form
  onSubmit={values => makeAPICall(values).catch(e => return { username: e })}
  // ...
  render={({
    handleSubmit,
    values,
    // ...
   }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Field name="username">
        {({ input, meta }) => (
          <div>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input {...input} type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            {meta.submitError && meta.touched && <span>{meta.submitError}</span>}
          </div>
        )}
      </Field>
    </form>
   )}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you. It wasn't clear to me what should the `catch` return. With a help of your answer and another look in a docs all made sense.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help